# How does a R2DBC repository work with Postgis geometries?

Tags: spring-boot, postgis, reactive, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I had a couple of entity classes that worked with Spring Data JPA.
(These entity classes are in a postgres db with postgis installed and contain geometry fields.)

However, when I switched to r2dbc, it did not work. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry!

```
@Entity
public class Place {
    @Id
    public int id;
    @Column(columnDefinition="Geometry")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")    
    public com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point coordinates;
}
```

Comment: You will have to use custom mapper like mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/#reference

Comment: @Tisha did you manage to get this working? I am currently also trying to use Postgis with R2DBC. I did write a custom converter as suggested above but to no avail yet

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel Not yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit more to the state of geometry and the R2DBC Postgres driver. Note that everything in this space is evolving so things may change quickly.

The R2DBC Postgres driver supports Postgres-internal geometry types (`point`, `line`, …) as of version 0.8.5. Those can be read and written through the driver types [`io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Point`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/blob/main/src/main/java/io/r2dbc/postgresql/codec/Point.java) and so on.

The R2DBC Postgres driver was built with an extension model so external codecs can be registered with the driver to support Postgres type extensions.

The Postgis JDBC driver has received recently a feature request asking for [R2DBC PostGIS support](https://github.com/postgis/postgis-java/issues/83).

The final bit is Spring Data. It requires a definition over which types are driver-native types so Spring Data can pass-thru complex types instead of trying to map these. There's [an open ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/423) to consider R2DBC Postgres' types as simple ones.

There's however no support for JTS in Spring Data as the primary focus is on the persistence model.

Answer (score 1):

r2dbc doesn't support  spatial data yet.